# how to remove an UIView in the table view cell programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

I have a table view cell like the picture above. I make an app for a tenant in the apartment to report the defect of the room facility. if the defect has been repaired, data from server will give `defect.status == 2` (if defect.status == 1, still on process to be repaired), at that time I will show the comment/response from user, if they satisfied or not. after they give respond either by pressing YES or NO. the UIView shall be removed, I mean the UIView that contains "Are You satisfied" label and Yes No Button like below and not appear again

[image]

I use the code below in the cellForRow at IndexPath method

```
if dataDefect.status == 2 {
   cell.commentResponseView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

[image]
but I got error found nil

here is my code in the view controller:

```
extension RequestDefectVC : UITableViewDataSource {

     //MARK: Table View Delegate & Datasource

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listDefects.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defectCell", for: indexPath) as! RequestDefectCell

        let dataDefect = listDefects[indexPath.row]
        cell.defectData = dataDefect

        if dataDefect.status == 3 {
            cell.commentResponseView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // to implement button delegate on RequestDefectCell Delegate
        cell.cellYesButtonDelegate = self
        cell.cellNoButtonDelegate = self
        cell.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }

}
```

and here is the code in my table view cell :

```
protocol RequestDefectCellYesButtonDelegate : class {
    func yesButtonDidPressed(defectID: Int)
}

protocol RequestDefectCellNoButtonDelegate : class {
    func noButtonDidPressed(defectID: Int)
}

class RequestDefectCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var defectImageView: DesignableImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var defectStatusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var defectCreationDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var defectDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentResponseView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var defectStatusLogo: UIImageView!

    weak var cellYesButtonDelegate: RequestDefectCellYesButtonDelegate?
    weak var cellNoButtonDelegate: RequestDefectCellNoButtonDelegate?



    @IBAction func yesButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let defectData = defectData else {return}
        cellYesButtonDelegate?.yesButtonDidPressed(defectID: defectData.defectID)
    }


    @IBAction func noButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {
         guard let defectData = defectData else {return}
        cellNoButtonDelegate?.noButtonDidPressed(defectID: defectData.defectID)
    }





}
```

I know it will probably because I already connect it to the cell

```
 @IBOutlet weak var commentResponseView: UIView!
```

but if I don't connect, I don't have any other idea

Comment: `commentResponseView` connected to outlet check it

Comment: and also you can us show/hide to view according to status

Comment: thanks for your answer Darwish, but i need to remove it from superview, because if i just hide it, it will remain a space between the label 'Keran Patah' to the bottom view of table view cell.

Comment: commentResponseView why is nil are you connected to IBoutlet in your cell or not

Comment: Why not change the data behind the table view? Either remove the entry from `listDefects` or set something to indicate the defect's been fixed. Then all you need to do is call `reloadData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide view instead of remove from cell because it will be reuse while scroll .

```
   if dataDefect.status == 3 {
          if let wantToRemoveView = cell.commentResponseView{
                 wantToRemoveView.removeFromSuperview()// OR wantToRemoveView.isHidden = true
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get that error after user action on those Yes or No buttons, then that may be because you have called `removeFromSuperview()` without checking it is already removed or not.

Because for `UITableView` if you have called `reloadData` or any other method which invokes your `cellForRowAt indexPath` method, then it will found `nil` for that view, because it is already removed in previous iteration of `cellForRowAt indexPath`.

So one solution is to check whether your view in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method is already removed or not like below:

```
if dataDefect.status == 3 && cell.commentResponseView != nil {
    cell.commentResponseView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Another solution is to set constraints in that manner in which if you set `commentResponseView`'s height constraint to 0, which hides it from your `UITableViewCell`, And then on specific condition set it to 0 in your `cellForRowAt indexPath` instead of removing that view from `UITableViewCell`. So the rest of the views will be managed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

try this codes

**Objective c**

```
[[cell. commentResponseView viewWithTag:MY_CUSTOM_TAG]removeFromSuperview] ;
```

swift

```
cell.commentResponseView.viewWithTag(MY_CUSTOM_TAG)?.removeFromSuperview()
```

another way you can do it through hide the commentResponseView of a corresponding cells and then change it constrains value